# progressbar not displaying in Relativelayout in webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-progressbar

I am developing an application containing a webview. I have `RelativeLayout` as a root element of the xml file. The `RelativeLayout` has `ProgressBar`,`SwipeRefreshLayout`,`WebView` and `AdView` elements included. By default, the visibility of `ProgressBar` is set to `gone`, it should appear while loading the webpage and again should invisible. But, It is not showing anytime. Here's my `activity_web_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.softglobe.allmedia.Showsite"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_states"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"/>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/swiperefresh"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I have tried using `LinearLayout` with `weight` and`weightsum` properties, then the `ProgressBar` is shown, but then `AdView` disppears. The code using LinearLayout is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.softglobe.allmedia.Showsite"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="20">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_states"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="18"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/swiperefresh"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me with this issue. I want both `ProgressBar` and `AdView`.
I am making `ProgressBar` visible in the `Siteview.java` file in the `onCreate` method. Following is the code

```
 final SwipeRefreshLayout finalMySwipeRefreshLayout1 = mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            // Visible the progressbar
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            finalMySwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: paste the code where you trying to visible your progress bar

Comment: @vikassingh I have added the code snippet

Comment: @AnisurRahmanTonu not a luck, still as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your SwipeRefreshLayout is on top of your ProgressBar, so even if you make your ProgressBar visible it will be shown under the SwipeRefreshLayout and you won't be able to see it, you can use

```
 `android:layout_below="@+id/pb"`
```

in your SwipeRefreshLayout Or you can make SwipeRefreshLayout visibility set to gone when your progress bar is visible and make SwipeRefreshLayout visible when ProgressBar is not.

Comment: it solved by including `android:layout_below="@+id/pb"` in the `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Override these two function as follows

```
 @Override
            public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(String url) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
```

Comment: try removing this line super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);